# How to handle characters not supported by the TextStyle fontFamily in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fonts, character

I am building an app using flutter on android package. The app is being tested on android device.
I have set TextStyle for different parts of the app using fonts downloaded from google fonts.
e.g.
TextStyle bodyStyle = GoogleFonts.lobsterTwo(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,);

The app is working well however, I noticed that texts using the TextStyle stated above does not display a placeholder symbol instead of certain characters such as 'ṣ' (a letter s with dot underneath).
I have searched on how to set a fall-back font for such characters but have found none.
Please can anybody help me with that.

Comment: are you using non-English as text?

Comment: Yes I am using non-English fonts. In Nigeria languages we have characters that are 'derived' from English fonts. Such as 'Ṣ', 'Ọ'. Basically they are English alphabets with dots underneath

Comment: can you include sample Text/Widget with the text which will reproduce the error